# Как устанавливать внутреннее окно браузера по желанию?

Tags: google-chrome

У автора обучающих видео есть такая настройка, которая позволяет изменять внутреннее окно браузера. Вот изображение: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автор использует Google Chrome. Где есть такие настройки? Как добавить такую возможность, как на изображении?

Comment: F12(devTools) -> ctrl+shift+M(toggle device toolbar). Он кстати на вашем скрине даже выделен(справа синий значок)

Comment: Спасибо. Давно пускал слюнки на эту возможность.